# JavaScript creating DOM elements behind the scences

Tags: javascript, html, dom

There are a some elements (HTML5) that are not supported or partially supported in some browsers.

I'm interested in what is happening when `document.createElement()` is used - an element is created and then if there is no support, it becomes text, which is not rendered?

Just out of a curiosity is there a way to see what elements are supported, something like a list of them, by using JavaScript and not by compatibility sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) the site gives detail about what is supported by your current browser.

http://html5test.com/

2) give full detail for every browser, what is supported and what is not

http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at these pages:
http://html5accessibility.com/
http://wufoo.com/html5/

They list up what elements are supported and not. What happens if the element is not supported depends on the browser.

You should take a look at http://modernizr.com/ . Which is a js-project that helps older browser to render and display html-elements.

Comment: I'm no interested in compatibility sheets. And how this answers the first question - " what is happening when document.createElement() is used "

Comment: try create some elements and display it in IE9 compatible mode then? You should be able to see the result youself. And the second question, no builtin function to display what is supported and not. you will have to do a test for each element.